# Dynamically load js content with iron router in meteor using array in return statement

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I would like to load the js content which belongs to the specified template by using iron router in meteor. The return statement returns plain text - It´s not useful for an array with some html-statements. How to **return** it by using the following array with the following html statement in **Template.info.helpers**?

> .js

```
Router.route('/', function () {
    this.render('info');
});

Router.route('info');

Router.route('/hello', function () {
    this.render('hello');
});

Template.info.helpers({
    info() {
        var iterate ="";
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            iterate += "<div class='row'>" + i + "</div>";
        }
        return iterate;
    } // Gives raw text -> Works NOT fine: <div class='row'>0</div><div class='row'>1</div>...
)};

Template.hello.helpers({
    hello() {
        var text = "Hello";
        return text;
    } // Works fine
)};
```

> .html

```
<template name="hello">
   <a href="{{pathFor route='info'}}">Home</a>
   </br>
   <a href="{{pathFor route='hello'}}">hello</a>
   <p>{{hello}}</p>
</template>

<template name="info">
   <a href="{{pathFor route='info'}}">Home</a>
   </br>
   <a href="{{pathFor route='hello'}}">hello</a>
   <p>{{info}}</p> <!-- Gives raw text -> Works NOT fine: <div class='row'>0</div><div class='row'>1</div> ... and so on -->
</template>
```

Please help. There allready was a usefully awnser, but I´ve got another problem now... :)

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. All the js should be there all of the time. Are you talking about your helpers?

Comment: For example, if I change `<a href="{{pathFor route='hello'}}">hello</a>` to `<a href="{{pathFor route='hello'}}">hello test</a>` in `<template name="info">` the hrefs displayed correctly. The helpers-content from the js in `<p id="info"></p>` won´t display. Instead of "Some info" and "Hello" there are variables: Like `var text = "Hello";`, but I think It doesn´t matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I get the question now. You're trying to directly manipulate the DOM from your helpers but the reality is that your helpers will never run because you're not referring to the helpers in your html. Not only that your helpers don't have any reactive data in them.

Far simpler than manipulating the DOM in your helpers, just have the helpers `return` the strings you need and insert them directly in your template with `{{hello}}` and `{{info}}`

js:

```
Template.info.helpers({
    info() {
        return "Some info";
    }
)};

Template.hello.helpers({
    hello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
)};
```

html:

```
<template name="hello">
   <a href="{{pathFor route='info'}}">Home</a>
   </br>
   <a href="{{pathFor route='hello'}}">hello</a>
   <p id="hello">{{hello}}</p>
</template>

<template name="info">
   <a href="{{pathFor route='info'}}">Home</a>
   </br>
   <a href="{{pathFor route='hello'}}">hello</a>
   <p id="info">{{info}}</p>
</template>
```

`{{hello}}` tells blaze *find the helper whose key is named "hello" and insert it here*.

Note that `{{> hello}}` and `{{hello}}` will do completely different things. The first will insert the entire *template* whose *name* is "hello" and the second will render the result of the "hello" *helper*.

If your helper is returning html instead of plain text then you'll need to use triple braces in your template, i.e.

```
{{{hellohtml}}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I´ll try tomorrow. It´s late right now.

Comment: It does not leave me in peace. I tried it with a return for a variable. I thought it is easier. Of course, a "return" returns plain text... What do I have to do if the variable is very, **very**, much more complex? Means it contains some html parts and the variable is an array. Like var  array =""; for (var = 0; i < 10; i++){array += "<div class='row'>"i"</div>";}

Comment: I was to slow for editing: It does not leave me in peace. I tried it with a return for a variable. It works! But... I thought it is easier. Of course, a "return" returns plain text... **What do I have to do if the variable is very, very, much more complex?** Means it contains some html parts and the variable is an array. Like `var  array =""; for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){array += "<div class='row'>" + i + "</div>";} return array;` -> Will return the plain text. In this way I have used the `document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML`, but the site needs to reload and won´t display immediatly.

Comment: @kornholio please that should be a new question. In the first place, doing the Meteor Blaze tutorial (possibly again) should already provide you some answers. Feel free to open a new question if you need further help.

Comment: @kornholio BTW do not forget to _accept_ this answer, since you say that it worked. Once you have enough _reputation_, you will also have the ability to _upvote_.